# Does anyone know if it is possible to extend a flutter widget?

Tags: flutter, widget

Is it possible to extend a widget? take for instance the CalendarDatePicker widget. I like the existing features but I want to be able to extend it.

I want to be able to have a little dot under each day that has some events whether it is just one or multiple events. If a day doesn't have any events, then nothing needs to show under that day. Events would be coming from a firebase Firestore.

The reasons are:

1. I like the CalendarDatePicker and I prefer not having to install a new package. I see people are using Table_Calendar. It is nice but I am trying to reuse leverage what is already there and stay away from installing too many packages.
2. I'd prefer not to design one from scratch when there is one that already does 98% of what needs to get done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend widgets and override its properties and methods with `extends` keyword (see [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class)). It is simple OOP inheritance. But anyway you should fully override build method to complement existing UI. Do it, copy existing code from CalendarDatePicker build method to you custom class build method and update this code as you wish:

```dart
class CustomDatePicker extends CalendarDatePicker {
  const CustomDatePicker({
    Key? key,
    // here you can use constructor properties that you need
    // and pass them to superclass constructor
  }) : super(...);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // use code from CalendarDatePicker build method
    // and update it as you wish
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had started using it that way but was having some issues. I figured it is very easy to just create one and i can pretty much add whatever i need. I just need to make sure i test it on more devices.